# A choice in previous question is unchecked if the user move to the next question and select a choice

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and HTML! I am currently implementing a questionnaire form. In the questionnaire URL, it shows questions and choices well. However, if the user moves to the next question and clicks a choice, the choice in the previous question is unchecked. Below is my **questoinnaire.html** code.

```
    {% if latest_question_list %}
    <form action="{% url 'results' %}" method="post">
        <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset>
            {{forloop.counter}}
            {{ question.question_text }}
            <hr>
            {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
               <input type="radio" name= "choice" id="choice{{forloop.counter}}" value={{choice.id}}>
               <label for="choice{{forloop.counter}}">{{choice.choice_text}}</label><br>
            </hr>
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Result">
    </form>
        </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No questionnaires are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

My questionnaire **models.py** is

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField('date published', null  = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):

        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime. timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True)
    value = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

And this is **views.py**

```
def question(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'questionnaire/question.html', context)
```

Comment: All radio buttons have the same `name`, please use same name only for options of the same question, the `name` should differ for options across different questions...

Answer (score 0):

Html forms treat radio buttons of the same name as one element. Each radio should have a name per question.

However, this html wont allow a user to unselect a choice. Would a checkbox be better?

```
       <input type="radio" name="choice{{forloop.counter}}" id="choice{{forloop.counter}}" value={{choice.id}}>
```